Почему "unsigned int x = -100" выдаёт значение 4294967196?
Почему unsigned int x = -100 выдаёт значение 4294967196?

Потому что при присвивании одного целого другому того же размера вне зависимости от "знаковости" (signed/unsigned) просто пересылаются все биты (из одной переменной (или литерала (как у вас -100) в другую). Значение -100 в hex FFFFFF9C, что равно 4294967196 unsigned в десятичной системе  (и это вы видите при печати, которая учитывает тип переменной (unsigned у вас))

(а вообще, это называется Дополнительный код, именно в нем хранятся значение целого типа)

Проиллюстрирую наглядно на Python, там внутри всё тоже на C на самом деле сделано. Да и вообще это кросс-языковая история.
import struct

data = struct.pack('>i', -100)      # упаковываем -100 в 4 байта как int32
print(data.hex().upper())           # печатаем эти байты в 16-ричном виде
print(struct.unpack('>I', data)[0]) # распаковываем как uint32 и печатаем

Вывод:
FFFFFF9C
4294967196

То есть смысл в чём. -100 - это знаковый тип int, размером 4 байта. Его 16-ричное представление в памяти - это FFFFFF9C. Когда происходит присваивание этого же значения в беззнаковый тип int, то берётся байтовое представление числа и воспринимается так, как будто туда было предварительно записано число без знака. Такое число без знака, которое соответствует байтовому представлению FFFFFF9C - это как-раз 4294967196.
Вообще система такая. Беззнаковые числа используют все 4 байта полностью. А у знаковых чисел для положительных чисел старший бит = 0, для отрицательных старший бит = 1. И счёт идёт от 0 в обратную сторону.
Т.е. 00000000 - это 0 и для знакового и для беззнакового.
А вот FFFFFFFF - это беззнаковое 4294967295 и знаковое -1.

Отрицательное целое -100 приводится к беззнаковому типу unsigned int. В этом случае стандарт C требует прибавлять к нему 232 до тех пор, пока новое значение не окажется в диапазоне [0, 232 - 1]. Достаточно одного прибавления, получится -100 + 232 = 4294967196.
На старых машинах/компиляторах возможна ситуация когда UINT_MAX = 65535. Тогда значение будет -100 + 216 = 65436. Если unsigned int занимает больше тридцати двух бит, результат тоже будет другой.
Короче, беззнаковое значение вычисляется по модулю UINT_MAX + 1.
C
Из черновика стандарта С11 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers:

2 Иначе, если новый тип беззнаковый, значение преобразуется последовательным добавлением или вычитанием значения на единицу большего максимального значения нового типа до тех пор, пока значение не окажется в диапазоне значений нового типа. 60)
…
60) Правила описывают математические операции, не операции данного типа.

Оригинал:

2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type. 60)
…
60) The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

C++
Из C++ reference, Implicit conversions, Integral conversions:


Если результирующий тип беззнаковый, результирующее значение – наименьшее беззнаковое значение равное исходному по модулю 2n,
где n – число бит результирующего типа.


Оригинал:


If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the smallest unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2n
where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type.


P.S. Все используют черновик стандарта, потому что сам стандарт платный, а черновик очень мало от него отличается.
P.P.S. Спасибо wololo за его комментарий, из которого и сделан этот ответ.

Потому что переполнение. 32 бита, 232 - 100 = 4294967196.

В данном случае это всё-таки наверное не переполнение, а неявное преобразование? И -100, а не -10?

@CrazyElf, нолик добавил, не принципиально. Ну преобразование биты не меняет. Если сделать -100U - получится то же самое, а со стороны переполнения ответ намного понятнее.

@Qwertiy, все же суть дела в том, что в данном случае биты как есть просто перемещаются из одного места в другое (и конечно, никаких переполнений физически не происходит)

@avp, автор спрашивает, почему получается конкретное значение. Если вместо приведения -100 из int к unsigned сделать сразу -100U, то результат будет тот же и это именно переполнение при применении унарного минуса к беззнаковому числу. В принципе, приведение типов тоже можно назвать переполнением, если значение не влезает в новый тип. А то, что тут просто копирование битов и длины одинаковые - это уже натягивание совы, потому что в unsigned-типе не может лежать отрицательное значение, а значит мы присваиваем значение за пределами диапазона и я имею право это назвать переполнением.

@Qwertiy, вы можете называть как вам нравится. Но все же, переполнение это ситуация, возникающая  во время вычислений, которое фиксируется аппаратурой и отражается в изменении битов v и c в статусном регистре. В данном случае ничего подобного при работе процессора не происходит

@avp, а (unsigned)1e12 - это переполнение или нет? А ещё гугл ничего мне не говорит о флаге v - возможно, ты имел в виду o?

@avp, C# считает такое присвоение переполнением: tio.tun и скриншот: https://i.sstatic.net/TpIZ3h4J.png

@Qwertiy, в aarch64 формально переполнения нет (аппаратно при этом преобразовании типа переполнение не выствляется, насколько я вижу). Ну, вообще-то я ничего не говорил о переполнениях при преобразовании типа, а говорил только о присваивании целых (причем одного размера) (говоря о флагах, я имел в виду n,z,v,c (насколько помню в x86 они такие же)). (А o от гугла -- это наверняка v -- oVerflow (впрочем, c (Carry) тоже часто свидетельсвует о преполнении))

@Qwertiy, в x86 float to integer conversions более правильны (интуитивны). При переполнении возникнет floating-point invalid exception

@avp, вот отдельным вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1598347/178988.

@CrazyElf, вот отдельный вопрос про переполнение тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1598347/178988.

По той же причине, по которой
int summ(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int main() {
    std::cout << summ(1.5, 1.5) << "\n";
}

работает (хоть и весьма неожиданно).
По той же причине, по которой
if (42) {
...
}

эквивалентен
if (true) {
...
}

Неявное преобразование типов
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion
Компилятор c++ "исходит из логики", что программист "знает что делает". Поэтому ведёт себя, как помощник, а не как контролёр. Есть ряд определённых допущений, которые позволяет себе делать компилятор. Но не всё подряд. Например при инициализации переменных списком инициализации сужающие преобразования недопустимы
unsigned int x { -100 }; // error

Плюсы - язык со статической типизацией, но не со строгой. Это даёт свои "плюшки" при написании кода и его оптимизации компилятором, но накладывает некоторую ответственность на программиста.
Следить за соответствием типов, границами обрабатываемых диапазонов - это зона ответственности программиста.
Добавлено:
Справедливости ради нужно отметить, что непосредственно самого объяснения почему -100 - это именно 4294967196 в моём ответе нет. Но объяснение, почему это так "на уровне байт" уже дали до меня и после меня.
Да, всё дело в способе представления значения того или иного типа в памяти. Так исторически (по весьма объективным причинам) сложилось, что представление положительного числа целочисленных типов (со знаком) и представление беззнакового целочисленного типа эквивалентны. А представление отрицательных чисел таково, что оно зависит от количества  бит/байт, выделенных для хранения данного типа. Разработчики стандарта не стали, естественно, изобретать что-то этакое и внесли в стандарт требования, которые буквально согласуются с "логикой машин". Довольно подробно со ссылками на стандарт и разложением чисел на битики это описано здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable
Хочу обратить ваше внимание, что когда размеры типов при преобразованиях разные - это уже не всегда простое побитовое копирование. И даже когда это просто копирование всех бит, оно может происходить на уровне инструкций процессора с отсечением. Всё это не важно. Важно - что об этом говорит стандарт самого языка, и что гарантированно им! Конкретно в случае unsigned int x = -100:

результатом является значение целевого типа, которое сопоставимо с
исходным целым числом по модулю 2^n, где n — ширина целевого типа
(количество бит).

Как этого добивается компилятор, какие именно инструкции под конкретную архитектуру он выбирает - это дело второе.

А {-100U} должно прокатить.

Ну да, прокатывает.
Интересно, а можно тут сказать, что мы инициализируем литерал типа unsigned литералом типа int?

Интересно.  https://godbolt.org/z/xb836WGdr gcc против инициализации литералом int, но не то чтобы очень против инициализации результатом функции типа int ) clang тут более категоричен. Они по разному интерпретируют зону ответственности заполнения списка инициализации. Кажется clang тут более логичен.

@sibedir Литерал по определению - неименованная константа в коде. 100U - литерал. А какая-то переменная, которую им инициализируют - уже не литерал, потому что именованная. Даже -100U уже не литерал, а выражение.

@HolyBlackCat, но тогда почему, если -100u - не литерал, unsigned int x { -100u } работает. Т.е. я как себе логику компилятора деконструирую. Если -100u - это выражение, допустим оно состоит из оператора - и литерала 100u. Тогда результатом этого выражения должен стать -100 типа int, которое в свою очередь "не лезет" в список инициализации для unsigned int. А раз оно пролезло. Значит изначальное предположение не верно. Значит он всю эту запись воспринимает, как литерал.

https://godbolt.org/z/dqePfKGE8 Что gss, что clang воспринимают запись -0x100u как одно целое как 4294967040 типа unsigned int (не настаиваю. просто так думаю. если не прав, буду рад исправлению)

@sibedir "должен стать -100 типа int" Не-а, результат останется типа unsigned int. Какого типа будет результат - никак не связано с тем, считается ли он литералом. Про литерал - это просто вопрос (правильной) терминологии.

@HolyBlackCat , ага, логику кажись понял. Как 1/3 не сделает результат типом float, а оставит типом int, так и -100u не сделает результат int-ом, а оставит беззнаковым. Но колечко развернёт.

А вот summ(1.5, 1.5) это явление совсем другой природы, нежели рассматриваемый ТС случай. В вашем примере (если отбросить оптимизацию на этапе компиляции) происходит преобразование  из типа double в int (она потребует (опять же, если отбросить оптимизацию) выполнения одной (или нескольких, зависит от архитектуры компа) машинных инструкций). Естественно, дробная часть при этом будет отброшена.

@avp , эмм... Но что есть природа? С точки зрения кода - это просто другие инструкции, не лучше и не хуже остальных. С точки зрения языка - это неявное преобразование. Ну или что Вы имели в виду под природой? Да, на уровне машинных кодов тут происходят разные вещи. Qwertiy уже продемонстрировал до меня, что именно. Я же хотел обратить внимание на формальную постановку вопроса. С точки зрения языка есть Integral conversions и есть Floating-integral conversions (и ещё другие). Они одной категории и ранга (что бы это ни значило). Механизм преобразование - это внутренняя кухня компилятора.

@sibedir, никто не запрещает вам программировать на уровне предоставляемых абстракций. Но как по мне, то лучше при этом понимать, что именно происходит в железе, которое мы собственно и программируем для решения задачи  (конечно, спускаться на уровень плотности электронов в разных участках кристалла  не стоит). (кстати, Qwertiy продемонстрирова неверно, там нет переполнения, есть только пересылка бит с одного адреса по другому)

Попробуй запустить эту программу:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN_CHAR_VALUE -128
#define MAX_CHAR_VALUE 127

int main()
{
    // char хранит один байт
    char i = MIN_CHAR_VALUE;
    for (; i < MAX_CHAR_VALUE; i++)
    {
        printf("signed: %d, unsigned: %u\n", i, (unsigned char) i);
    }

    printf("signed: %d, unsigned: %u\n", i, (unsigned char) i);

    return 0;
}

Этот код выводит все значения i в знаковом и беззнаковом виде.
Чтобы не мучиться, вот результат:
signed: -128, unsigned: 128
signed: -127, unsigned: 129
signed: -126, unsigned: 130
...
signed: -8, unsigned: 248
signed: -7, unsigned: 249
signed: -6, unsigned: 250
signed: -5, unsigned: 251
signed: -4, unsigned: 252
signed: -3, unsigned: 253
signed: -2, unsigned: 254
signed: -1, unsigned: 255
signed: 0, unsigned: 0
signed: 1, unsigned: 1
signed: 2, unsigned: 2
signed: 3, unsigned: 3
...
signed: 119, unsigned: 119
signed: 120, unsigned: 120
signed: 121, unsigned: 121
signed: 122, unsigned: 122
signed: 123, unsigned: 123
signed: 124, unsigned: 124
signed: 125, unsigned: 125
signed: 126, unsigned: 126
signed: 127, unsigned: 127

Сначала, когда у нас было максимальное отрицательное значение, у беззнакового значение было на 1 больше максимального знакового.
Знаковое приближалось к -1, а беззнаковое — к 255.
Затем знаковое стало равным 0, и беззнаковое тоже стало нулём.
Далее значения приближались к максимальному знаковому (127) как у знакового, так и у беззнакового типов.
То же самое будет для int, short и т.д.

unsigned int - это безнаковый тип, который не может быть меньше 0.
4294967196 берётся потому, что это максимальное число допустимое данным типом от которого отнимается 100. Хотя принимаемое значение может отличаться в зависимости от компилятора.

Этот ответ поясняет, что unsigned int не может быть отрицательным, но не объясняет, почему при присвоении -100 получается значение 4294967196. Попробуйте уточнить, как происходит преобразование отрицательного значения в беззнаковое и почему возникает такой результат. [edit]
